# Color recognition with live camera in flutter

Tags: flutter, camera, object-detection, object-recognition, color-detection

Does anyone know how to implement color recognition with live camera on flutter? I have implemented object detection but also wish to recognize the object's color as well but have no idea how to do it. Here to look for some guidance. Thank you in advance.

Example result from AIPoly Vision application:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhPgw.jpg)